# Projection of portion of solid onto $xy$ plane - the solid being bounded by a surface and $3$ planes

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Consider the solid bounded by the surface $z =\sqrt{x}$ and the planes
> $x + 2y = 4$ , $y = 0$, and $z = 0$.
>
> (a) Sketch the projection of the
> portion onto the $xy$-plane

I am unsure of what this projection looks like before I put it into graphing software. I know I need to find the bounds but I am unsure why how.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The $x-y$ plane has equation $z=0$. So, putting $z=0$ in your equations, you find the equations of the lines that bound the region.